# Password generation algorithm used by MacOS keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

What algorithm does MacOS use in its keychain system to generate passwords? (using password assistant accessed through keychain app and using Safari keychain).

Does it access/is it the GUI for the `/dev/*random` interface used in terminal? Or is it entirely a separate process?

Comment: Have you seen the output to `/dev/*random`?